# ImageResolution Doesn't Work!

Tags: graphics, export

The code below is supposed to generate a high resolution plot, but it does not!

```
g = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}];
Export["c:/sin.jpg", g, ImageResolution -> 600]
```

[image]

I have the same problem with exporting other graphic objects. What should I do?

Comment: It plots just fine on 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014). Maybe you should switch to a different format, such as PDF. What is not as you expect it?

Comment: Related [Quality control when exporting graphics into JPG](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26364/quality-control-when-exporting-graphics-into-jpg)

Comment: @Lou I'm using 8.0. I expect a 600 dpi jpg output.

Comment: Plots just fine 9.0 Win7-64. Compare ImageResolution -> 600 with ImageResolution -> 6. Documentation for ImageResolution also says "ImageResolution is relevant only for bitmap graphics formats such as "PNG", and not for resolution‐independent formats such as "SVG"." Docs for previous versions worded that differently. So try exporting a bitmap graphics image like PNG and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @Bill Thanks. With png, everything's OK.

Comment: Related: [Rasterize: Resolution option not working properly](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64758/18476).

Comment: Sort of unrelated, but in general one should always export images as either "PDF" or "PNG"; "JPG" tends to produce ugly graphics due to quantization error, and is better suited for photographs of people.