# Exporting Graphics

Tags: graphics, export

I saved the following graph from *Mathematica*

[image]

The graph is very smudgy and it looks very bad when I embedded it in the TeX file. What are more efficient ways to neatly present graphical outputs from *Mathematica* in TeX etc.

I can provide the codes required to generate the graphs on request.

Comment: "The graph is very smudgy" - how exactly did you save the picture and transfer it to your $\TeX$ document?

Comment: Relevant: [1542](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/exporting-graphics-to-pdf-huge-file?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @J.M. Simply exported it as a JPEG file and added it in the TeX file using the `figure` environment. Compared to the graph in this paper, http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.5228.pdf, my results are of second standard.

Comment: *jpeg* is a lossy format, it is better to export in a lossless format like *png* if you specifically want to export in image format.

Comment: I often do this for journal publications. The journal requirement is eps format. The eps created by Mma is, however, not the same as the standard one. For this reason I save the image in pdf format and then with the CorelDraw convert the pdf into eps. The result is the image quality good enough for Physical Review.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Is there a free version of Corel Draw available?

Comment: @JunaidAftab You can use free `pdftops` utility for conversion as I describe at the bottom of [this](http://superuser.com/a/650524/71768) answer.

Comment: @Junaid Aftab I do not know, but I do not think that CorellDraw may be free. However, you may use any other graphics redactor that has an option to export into eps. As one possibility AdobeIllustrator has such. Alexei Popkov gives another possibility.

Comment: @JunaidAftab try Gimp (which is free) to convert the PDF to EPS ... http://www.lakewoodsound.com/misc/pdf2eps-gimp.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The default value of CompressionLevel is 0.25. Decreasing this will help to give better jpegs. The other thing you can do is to set the ImageSize larger.

Try:

```
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "exportTrial.jpg",  **YOUR_DATA**, "JPG", "CompressionLevel"->0]
```

From a similar question:
[Quality control when exporting graphics into JPG](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26364/quality-control-when-exporting-graphics-into-jpg)